# $End_{R}(R)\cong R$

Tags: abstract-algebra, graded-rings, ring-isomorphism

How can i prove that $End_{R}(R)\cong R$ as graded rings?
The map of isomorphism is
$$F:R→End(R),F(r)=fr,$$
where fr(a)=ar?

Comment: Why graded? You seem to be considering only one ring. Also,what is $\operatorname{End}(R)$ here? Ring endomorphisms or $R$-module endomorphisms?

Comment: Looks like you are looking at the ring of (left) $R$-module endomorphisms. Don't you get $End(R)\cong R^{opp}$ instead? After all, $f_r\circ f_s=f_{sr}$?